# Apollo Client / GraphQl query by non ID Field

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, prisma-graphql

I do not understand how to query a table by a non ID field in a graphql database. I follow the current documentation, and GraphQL throws an error saying the field I am using to query does not exist.

I am using Apollo with GraphQL and Prisma. I am brand new to all of these technologies. I am trying to build an app to organized mp3 recordings, so I am trying to build a database to store information about each recording. I am starting with a single Table, and I want to be able to query using the file path field.

I have the following schema:

```
model RecordingFile {
  id           String   @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  name         String
  path         String
  duration     Float
  size         Int
  tag          Tag[]
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt    DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(6)

}
```

AFAIK, I need to write a query using a variable, as stater [here in the GraphQL Docs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables)

Here is the query I think I should run:

```
query GetExisting($path: String!) {
    videoFile(path: $path) {
        id
        name
        path
    }
}
```

However this produces error: GraphQLDocumentError: Cannot query field "videoFile" on type "Query". Did you mean "videofile" or "videofiles"?

For context, I did initially name some entities as "videofile" but changed to camel case to match all my Typescript types. If I change the query to use 'videofile, I get the following errors:

```
      Error 0: GraphQLDocumentError: Unknown argument "path" on field "Query.videofile".
      Error 1: GraphQLDocumentError: Field "videofile" argument "id" of type "String!" is required, but it was not provided.
```

I am using the following packages:

"@apollo/client": "3.7.0",
"graphql": "15.8.0",
"prisma": "4.4.0",

Can anybody verify how to query using a non ID column? Like I said, I am new to  GraphQl, and I've seen some verbiage suggesting you cannot query non-ID fields, which I would think is crazy, plus its own documentation shows otherwise. Still, when I try to use [this tool](https://apollo-fullstack-tutorial.herokuapp.com/graphql), I can't seem to build a working query not using an ID. Also, forums seem to have lots of outdated solutions involving Typescript functions and parameters containing objects with "where" properties, but these seem to refer to older versions of graphql

### Update - Code example

Here is the code I want to run, ultimately. Like I said, I'm working with React using an Apollo client to query my server.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

interface NodeTableRowParams {
    data: {
        file: {
            name: string,
            path: string
            // ... other fields
        }
        // ... other fields
    }
}


const FIND_BY_PATH = gql`
query GetExisting($path: String!) {
    videoFile(path: $path) {
        id
        name
        path
    }
}
`


const NodeTableRow:React.FC<NodeTableRowParams> = ({data}) => {

    const { loading: loading_findByPath, error: error_findByPath, data: data_findByPath} = useQuery(FIND_BY_PATH, {
        variables: { path: data.file.path }
    });

    return (
        <div id="file=list">
            <FileData data={data}/>
        </div>
    );
});
```

However, as far as I can tell, I cannot build the app because graphql is not able to compile my query

Comment: Every GraphQL server can have a completely independent shape - GraphQL is just the "query language" to speak with the server. You will have to look at the Schema of your server to see which methods of interaction it offers. Nobody will be able to give you a general answer here.
It's a bit like you're asking "how to call a function that does X", but nobody except for you knows which functions you have written in your code base.

Comment: @phry yes, I specified I'm using Apollo Server/Client using prisma. The function I ultimately wants to use is  useQuery from  apollo/client. I am just trying to run   graphql code-gen - not sure what that does but I assume it looks at my graphql queries and generates typescript, yes? I cannot get my server running until I fix my query. Ultimately I am just trying to clarify my understanding of graphql and determine how to properly query my prisma DB using a non-ID column using graphql

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed the prisma part. I haven't used prisma in half a decade, and at this point I believe they market the product as an ORM that's easy to integrate with a GraphQL server, not as a GraphQL server per se. So I assume you still write your own GraphQL server here. At that point, I'd advise you to separate problems here: even without GraphQL in the picture at all, how do you get the data out of Prisma in your own server code, for a fixed search? After you figured that out, you can learn about exposing that through a variable. These are separate questions.

Comment: Served by Apollo Server. The data is served by apollo.... again, im not concerned with the server here. The errors I stated in the post come from running `graphql-codegen` on the front end, not the server. The Typescript fn I posted comes from Apollo Client... . As stated, I am just trying to verify 2 things. 1. is syntax correct, as per Graphql v. 15.8? And 2. is there anything about graphql/prisma/apollo server that would prevent me from querying by a non ID field?

Comment: The schema you show up there is not a GraphQL schema. It is a prisma schema. You need to look at your GraphQL Schema (which might be autogenerated by prisma, or hand-written by you to some extend by writing code for Apollo Server, again, I do not know that part). You can only write queries against fields and arguments that are defined in your GraphQL schema. You cannot just invent field arguments on the client - you would have to adjust your server GraphQL schema for that, or use arguments already available.

Comment: Again: your client code is a hundred steps away from the questions you should be answering right now. 
You need to figure out if there is a query you can send to your server that answers your question, or if you need to do adjustments to your server. You can do that by looking at your GraphQL Schema (which will contain all possible arguments), or by using something like a GraphiQL web interface. If that's not possible, you'll need to adjust your server further. You only get to the point to write React JavaScript after you have found out all that.

Comment: The same goes for the Codegen. For the question you want to answer here right now, that's just not of concern. It's just one of many tools that could error here because your query is not matching what's possible with your schema. If the codegen would not error, the server itself would error if you sent this query to it.

Comment: The schema I have I got from graphql. https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: " You can only write queries against fields and arguments that are defined in your GraphQL schema."  - so how do i change my schema to allow querying by a non-ID field?

Comment: > so how do i change my schema to allow querying by a non-ID field?
That's probably the question to ask,  and it might be a new question to ask on Stack Overflow so it is seen by the right people. This question was asked with about 5 different technologies in mind, so it's unlikely anyone with the right technologies looked at it. Ask a new question, concentrate on Prisma.

Comment: > The schema I have I got from graphql. graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

That's a generic documentation page. They don't know how your schema looks like, they just give generic advice against a made-up schema regardings star wars characters.

Comment: @phry Thanks for your help. I figured out my challenges. You pushed me down a path that lead to me researching the role of services and resolvers. In my Resolver, that is where I declared that I wanted to pass in a 'path' argument, and in my service, I wrote a specific method to search by path.... Ultimately, I just ended up writing my own endpoint. I just wanted to check the existence of a record and return if available. I can't seem to do that with prisma without throwing a "Cannot return null" error.

Comment: Great to hear I could give you a little push in the right direction, thank you for letting me know :)